# Html in json - how to make it valid (with javascript)?

Tags: javascript, json, json.net, html-encode

I'm using json.net to automatically deserialize my json objects into .net objects. As long as the json is valid, it works a treat.

But I'm having trouble with html in the json...the special characters and quotes are making the json invalid.

How do I encode or escape the html reliably so it's valid json? I need a way to do it with just javascript because it's the client side sending to the server side.

**Edit**
Just to give an example of my use case, I have a WYSIWYG in my app and I need the input from that included as part of a json object to be posted to my server.

Comment: why to pass html in json?

Comment: @lolbas Just edited with a use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just to give an example of my use case, I have a WYSIWYG in my app
>   and I need the input from that included as part of a json object to be
>   posted to my server.

Assuming you have the user input in a string variable:

```
var userInput = 'Any crap with HTML you can imagine';
```

You can simply JSON encode this in order to transport it as a valid JSON string:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ value = userInput });
```

Now the resulting object will look like this:

```
{
    "value": "Any crap with HTML you can imagine"
}
```

and on your server simply map this to a POCO with a plain `Value` string property. The `JSON.stringify` method will ensure to properly serialize any input to a valid JSON string.

This being said, I don't quite understand your need of wrapping the user input in a JSOn string and then deserializing it back on the server with JSON.NET. I would rather send the raw input as-is. This way you would get exactly the same value on the server without the overhead of JSON serialization.

Comment: The reason I need it into json is there is more than just that input I need sent at the same time. Basically I'm making an email client, so I need the recipient addresses, cc, from, html (from the WYSIWYG input), and some others.

Comment: Sure, but the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (which is what standard HTML forms use) will perfectly fine fit this case. You can send an arbitrary number of values to the server at the same time.

Comment: Ok, two questions. 1. re: stringify, when it serializes it, is that still valid html, i.e. can I use that as the html for the email, or do I need to deserialize that somehow? 2. How would I use application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will serialize the original value to a JSON string. If your original value was not valid HTML don't think that this method will fix it. It will guarantee you that you will get the exact same value on the server safely encoded. As far as the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is concerned, you could use a simple `<form>` with input elements and a `submit` button. When the form is submitted to the server as long as your input elements have names the values will be encoded and safely transmitted to the server.